# Android Post to Rails Server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup a survey that my app users can take that will post the results to a rails app. The survey/questions/answers are built in the rails app, then displayed in the Android app. After the user answers each question it should post back to the server.

I suspect that it's something to do with my create method (the uncommented line works for creating a choice in the rails app but not for the Android post and the commented line appears to work for neither) but I'm relatively new to Android/Rails so any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my ChoicesController:

```
class ChoicesController < ApplicationController

  # POST /choices
  # POST /choices.json
  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @choice = @question.choices.build(choice_params)
    @choice.answer = Answer.find(params[:choice][:answer_id])
    # @choice.answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @choice.save
        format.html { redirect_to question_choices_path, notice: 'Choice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @choice }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @choice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My choice model:

```
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  validates :question_id, presence: true
  validates :answer_id, presence: true
end
```

Here's how I'm creating/posting my json in Android:

```
public boolean postChoice(String apiKey) {
        boolean choicePosted = false;

        try {
            post();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        choicePosted = true;
        return choicePosted;
    }
    public static void post() {
        Map<String, String> choice = new HashMap<String, String>();
        choice.put("question_id", "6");
        choice.put("answer_id", "15");
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(choice, Map.class);
        makeRequest("http://localhost:3000/choices/", json);
    }

    public static HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the biggest problem I had was that I was not sending a CSRF token with my POST. including   `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` solved my problem. Since it's an API I have a few other security verification piece in place, but CSRF really only applies to web forms anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One big problem with your code is:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You are swallowing all exceptions and my guess you are also swallowing the problem exception. You should look into logs what exception is recorded and also not use catch (`Exception e`) but instead have explicit exception.

Without actual exception it hard to diagnose, but my guess is that you are making this http request inside UI thread and Android framework explicitly forbids it (it makes your app non-responsive) and throws an exception.

Comment: That makes sense. Any recommendations for what kind of exception I should catch?

Comment: Java will tell you about all explicit exceptions thrown, so it seems you are catching everything you need. Exception about running http request UI should not be caught, because it should never be done and it's intended to give you information for fixing the code.